# Fetching/Retrieving data from realtime firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am retrieving data from firebase, as you can see that whole data is coming in the console but am not able to render it on screen/UI because the data structure format is in-depth as you can see in image, after "orders" collection, then userId then orderId then data, I want this whole data to be on screen.

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import fireDb from "./firebase";

const App = () => {
  var [productObjects, setProductObjects] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    fireDb
      .child("orders")
      .on("value", (snapshort) => {
        if (snapshort.val() != null)
          setProductObjects({
            ...snapshort.val(),
          });
        else setProductObjects({});
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(productObjects);
return (null)
```